Column takes all available space
This code is meant for a browser. If I remove the marked column from the code, the cards just go from top to bottom, even though size is set everywhere to be minimum. I found this fix by change and I do not understand why this fixes my UI. Is there a more elegant way to prevent this from happening?
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:google_tasks_clone/task_lists_cubit.dart';
import 'package:google_tasks_clone/widgets/reset_button.dart';

enum TaskOption { delete }

enum TaskListOption { delete }

class WebHomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const WebHomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final state = context.watch<TaskListsCubit>().state as TaskListsLoadedState;
    final taskLists = state.taskLists;
    List<Widget> taskListWidgets = [];
    for (final taskList in taskLists) {
      final tasks = state.getUncompletedTasksFrom(taskList);
      final taskWidgets = tasks
          .map((task) => ListTile(
            title: Text(task.name),
            titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
            subtitleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
            subtitle: Text(task.description, maxLines: 1),
            leading: Checkbox(
              value: task.isCompleted,
              onChanged: (value) {
                context.read<TaskListsCubit>().toggleTask(task);
              },
            ),
            trailing: PopupMenuButton<TaskOption>(
              onSelected: (option) => switch (option) {
                TaskOption.delete => context.read<TaskListsCubit>().deleteTask(task),
              },
              itemBuilder: (context) => [
                const PopupMenuItem(
                  value: TaskOption.delete,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.delete),
                      SizedBox(width: 8),
                      Text('Delete'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ))
          .toList();
      taskListWidgets.add(
        Column( // <---------------------------------- this is the column that if removed, the UI will break
          children: [
            Card(
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                width: 300,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(taskList.name, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium),
                        PopupMenuButton(itemBuilder: (context) => []),
                      ],
                    ),
                    ListView(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      children: taskWidgets,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: const [ResetButton()],
        title: const Text('Google Tasks'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: taskListWidgets.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => taskListWidgets[index],
      ),
    );
  }
}

With the Column

Without the Column


you need to read this for understanding constrains in flutter:
https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/constraints
let me explain based on your case:

Constraints go down:  Widgets tell their children what constraints to obey.

Column widget tells its children that they can be any height. So when you wrap your Card with a Column , Card is free to be as tall as it wants.

Sizes go up: Widgets pass their own size up to their parent widget

Column uses the size information from the children which is the Card widget. And the Card widget decides its size based on its content ( since you set shrinkWrap:true in your ListView and this will not take infinite height) .
Then  the Column use the size information to decide its own size. By default The Column widget in Flutter does not expand to fill the available space : read here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html

Parent sets position: A widget can decide its own size, but it's the widget's parent that decides where the widget is positioned

in your case, the Column is deciding where to position the Card, and again, by default its MainAxisAlignment.start which is on the top.
thats why, there are more spcaes below the List of card at the end.

Thanks a lot for the explanation. I read the documentation about constraints and I think I got the hang of it. But what would be the best substitution for that column, since it seems a little redundant (it only has one child)? I think I would need something else that just fills the screen and lets the card be any size it wants to be. A simple Container does not work, for some reason.
